# Ubuntu 20.4 Mysql access from remote IP with PHP issue

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, ubuntu-20.04

I want to access to MySQL db on an Ubuntu Server from another Web server.
I get my web server outgoing IP with this PHP script running on the Web server:

```
$realIP = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
echo "Real IP: $realIP<br>";
```

I opened the ufw port on the Mysql Server:

```
sudo ufw allow from realIP_result to any port 3306
```

I change the Mysql configuration file to accept remote connections:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

and then edit updated the bind-address to 0.0.0.0:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

I create the user on MySQL Server:

```
CREATE USER 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

I created in this way, but I also tried without the mysql_native_password.

I grant all to that user:

```
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD on *.* TO 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I flush privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And when I try to connect from the web server with this PHP script:

```
$conn2=mysqli_connect("MYSQLIP","sammy","password","mydbname");
// Check connection
if ($error = mysqli_connect_error($conn2)) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $error;
  exit();
}
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /customers/e/9/2/mysite/myscript.php on line XX Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection timed out
```

How can I resolve, or debug further?

Comment: have you checked for outbound firewall restrictions on the web server?

Comment: mmm, the web server is an hosting in one.com, how can I check this?

Comment: If it's a VPS you host yourself, you should have terminal access at least where you could check? If not then contact the hosting company for support.

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is the problem because I can access from my IP with a client.